# Jquery Submit form which is added upon successful submission of form to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Need help in jquery:

here is a schema of code:

1. submit form through jquery to php
2. php sends another form upon submission
3. again submit form without page refresh and this continues forever.

sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".message-submit-button").click(function(){   
        var element = $(this);
        var Id = element.attr("id");
        var messageinput = $("#messageinput"+Id).val();
        var action = $("#action"+Id).val();
        var dataString = 'messageinput='+ messageinput + '&mobilenumber=' + Id + '&action=' + action;

        if(messageinput=='')
        {
            alert("Please Enter Message");
            document.getElementById('messageinput'+Id).focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#flash"+Id).show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert_message.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#flash"+Id).hide();
                    $("#message-content"+Id).replaceWith(html); 
                }
            });

        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

In above script, please note that the output "html" is none other than a same form with different set of ids.

above code is working fine for first form, but not for the second or so on. Please help for continues form submission.

Note: Upon submission the form to 'insert_message.php', it returns another form in a div tag with different set of ids but same inputs and classnames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the form is the same just with different ids, just change the ids. If you must change the form you'll have to re-attach the event handler or you can use delegation

```
$(document).on("click", ".message-submit-button", function(){
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

If your not on jquery 1.7+ you can use delegate instead

```
$(document).delegate(".message-submit-button", "click", function(){
```

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Thank you for faster response. I tried your suggestion, but it is not working. In each form, only form name, and input ids changes(including submit button). But the form is output from php which is passed through ajax submission.

Comment: Did you change `$(".message-submit-button").click(function(){` to `$(document).on("click", ".message-submit-button", function(){?`

Comment: yes, I changed it, upon changing it, it is not even triggering the empty message alert.

Comment: does the new form submit button have the `message-submit-button` class?

Comment: yes, this form is generated by php and only id values are changed each time.

Comment: yes, here is it `TypeError: $(document).on is not a function`

Comment: Then your version of jQuery doesn't have `.on()` you'll need to upgrade, but if you cant upgrade you can use delegate instead

Comment: using the latest jquery just downloaded from jquery site. `(File name: jquery-1.7.2.min.js)` Tried both answers, still getting same error.

Comment: I can't see any problem in  the code, can you produce a live demo?

Comment: Just re-downloaded the file and fixed the problem. Thank You very much for your help Musa.